# Outside JavaScript function returning an error when used inside another function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that I'm trying to make update a database when an event triggers. However, inside of the actual event code, no outside functions are running

Function(s) I'm trying to run:

```js
async log(text, type) {
  if (!type) console.log(`${Chalk.bgGreen(new Date().toUTCString())} ${text}`);
  if (type == 'warn') console.log(`${Chalk.bgYellow(new Date().toUTCString())} ${text}`);
  if (type == 'error') console.log(`${Chalk.bgRed(new Date().toUTCString())} ${text}`);
  if (type == 'cmd') console.log(`${Chalk.bgBlue(new Date().toUTCString())} ${text}`);
  if (type == 'db') console.log(`${Chalk.bgMagenta(new Date().toUTCString())} ${text}`);
}
```

```
var d = this.client.data.load()
console.log(d)
```

The function where I'm running my code:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(user);
  return reaction.emoji.name === "" && user.bot === false;
};

let collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {
  time: 60000,
  max: 2
});

collector.on('collect', async (reaction, collector) => {
  var d = this.client.data.load()
  console.log(d)
  message.delete();
  this.log('Database updated', 'db')
});
```

I'm also trying to access my log function (usually accessed at `this.log()`, however it's still returning an error).

I've gotten a multitude of errors, including the log not being able to be accessed, etc. I tried awaiting/asyncing the function as well and that didn't work either.

I believe this is an error with JavaScript and how scope works, however any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use `this` inside that event handler to refer to the parent object. You could create a `self = this;` reference higher up and use that, or make your logger part of the window globals.

Comment: Where do you recommend I put the `self = this`?